# How to == Model Method Class in Helper for CSS?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

**calendar_helper**

```
def day_classes(day)
  classes = []
  classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
  classes << "future" if day > Date.today # This make future days a white background, by default days are blue background
  # The Below Line Gives an Error (I want missed_dates date_missed to be red background): 
  classes << "missed" if day == current_user.missed_dates.group_by {|i| i.date_missed.to_date}
end
```

**NameError in Pages#home**

```
undefined local variable or method 'current_user'
```

**css**

```
.future { background-color: #FFF; }
.missed { background-color: red; }
```

I built the calendar off of a [railscasts tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndBKSjAbemo).

Comment: Regarding the `current_user`. Are you using `devise` gem or any other authentication gem that provides this helper, or have you defined (somewhere) the `current_user` helper method yourself?

Comment: Try using `SessionsHelper.current_user` instead of just `current_user` in your calendar_helper

Comment: Also, this line `classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")` can be simplified to `classes.join(' ') unless classes.empty?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your `Calendar` class:

```
delegate :current_user, to: :view
```

Since `SessionsHelper` is get automatically included into view, it should be able your `view` variable, that is getting passed to your `Calendar` class.

> Thank you that removed the error, but for some reason the days that I marked as date_missed didn't turn red

I guess `current_user.missed_dates.group_by {|i| i.date_missed.to_date}` is an array of missed dates, so, in order to check if your day is in that array, use `include?`:

```
missed_dates = current_user.missed_dates.group_by {|i| i.date_missed.to_date}
classes << "missed" if missed_dates.include?(day)
```